# Is there any option to migrate website from .NET 4.8 to .NET 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-7.0

I want to convert my ASP.NET website running on .NET 4.8 to .NET 7.

Is there any option to directly migrate the complete application with making extra effort?

Or is there any option to share session between .NET 4.8 and .NET 7?

Comment: If this is a mvc web site then little changes and it's easy to upgrade in most cases.  However there's no upgrade assistant for web forms due to the vast different architecture. So for web forms, that requires a whole re-write and even requires a whole rewrite even when keeping. Net framework.  Code upgrade from. Net framework to .net core is rather minor. However. Net core has no support for webforms. So if existing site is mvc, then no problem.  If web forms then that's a full rewrite of the application

Comment: I stand somewhat corrected, and the upgrade assistant does work with webforms. I does not wind up converting code, but does setup a .net core web site that runs in front of the webforms site. This is not great, but certainly better then nothing. See my answer in regards to how this works, and a link explaining what occurs when you use the upgrade assistant against a webforms project.

Answer (score 2):

Just to explain on this issue.

The upgrade assistant can be used with a web forms site.

The end result is no conversion actually occurs, but you do wind up with a site that runs under .net core.

The setup results in this:

[image]

So, what occurs is a .net core web site is placed in "front" of your asp.net webforms site. This setup THEN allows your developer(s) to move one page at a time from the asp.net webforms site over to the asp.net core site.

So, while no such code or design conversion occurs against the webforms site, it does give your developers "breathing" room and time to then start converting each asp.net webforms page to a .net core MVC or blazer syntax page. This of course is not an automated process, but will require you to re-develop the web page from scratch into the newer .net core MVC (or blazer) syntax pages. It is a hand code process and is certainly not any kind of automated conversion. However this approach does mean you have a .net core web site running, and in the mean time, you can run + use your existing web site despite the front facing web site being a .net core one.

How this works it outlined here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/inc/start?view=aspnetcore-7.0

So, the migration assistant will not convert your code, but it can move the asp.net webforms application to run "behind" a .net core site. You will have a working webforms site, but now at your leisure and over time can begin the task of re-writing each web form page into the newer .net core format.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your best option is [Upgrade Assistant](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.upgradeassistant) done by Microsoft.

Check also [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant-now-in-visual-studio/). If you want to do this incrementally, your best way to go is `Side-by-side incremental`. This will allow you to route traffic to old application for endpoints you didn't migrate yet.

Comment: upgrade assistant is not applicable for websites application. please suggest another option?

Comment: Where did you get that?
According to blog post I sent:
"Supported ASP.NET": https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant-now-in-visual-studio/#supported

Comment: In a "round about" way, yes, the upgrade assistant has provisions and options for webforms sites. The end result is a webform site running behind the .net core site. No conversion of code occurs, but this does get your site up and running and working with a .net core site (that runs in front of the web forms site).  Keep in mind the upgrade assistant really never did much of any code converting, since .net framework and .net core is in most cases indistinguishable  from a developers point of view, and from a code syntax point of view anyway. See my answer - upgrade does support webforms